# Penthao BI server on Ubuntu 10.4 Error Catalina

Tags: java, ubuntu-10.04, pentaho

I have fershly installed BI server for Pentaho on Ubuntu 10.4. when i start the pentaho from console using sh command and go to localhost my browser gives me unable to connect error. i looked at catalina.out file and this line we written

> ./catalina.sh: 454: ”/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle″/bin/java: not found

i dont know what is causing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java7 is not supported anyway with Pentaho BI Server, see here:

http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/BISERVER-6923

( although it may work, but given the above issue implies work needs to be done it doesnt seem worth taking the risk )

So install java6, and ensure your JAVA_HOME is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have the double quotes around /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle, I guess. It probably comes from a JAVA_HOME variable set somewhere...